# I only want the latest version of Python on my Windows machine

Tags: python, installation

There are many answers on how to remove old Python versions and many on how to install new ones. Is there a way to install the latest Python version so that it replaces all old installations please?

I don't want to use a virtual environment, BTW.

Comment: An installer that automatically removes an existing installation has a large potential to be destructive. So, no there is no such thing. You have to remove the old versions manually. My personal advice: Keep them and get used to virtual environments. You want to use them but you just don't know that yet.

Comment: @KlausD. How would venvs help with multiple python versions? Curious

Comment: OP - if you really need this, you could make yourself a script `.bat` that would uninstall  the version you have, and install a new one. But I don't think it's worth the extra effort

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Is this a new question or did you interpret something into my comment that was neither there nor intended?

Comment: @KlausD. could be neither, could be both, idk. You suggested OP keeps old python versions, and uses venvs instead, so I wanted to know, how is that relevant? Aren't venvs used to keep different versions of packages within one version of python?

Comment: No, I suggested to keep the old versions and *get used* to venvs. I never said that one is a replacement for the other.

Comment: If you are using a Linux or MacOS environment and the version you want to get rid of is the version of Python that came with the OS, you could do significant damage to your system by uninstalling it.

Comment: some modules may not work with the newest version and authors need some time to recompile modules for new Python - so it is better to use little older version and wait few months before you change to newest version. Other problem: every version uses own modules so installing new version it needs also to install all modules again.

Answer (score 0):

remove all versions of python and by rightclicken on them end pressing uninstall, this will open the programs and features panel and just remove all versions of python you have there, then install the latest version via the python website. this process will not take very long.

Comment: But what about the various folders, including those in users/AppData? Do they get deleted automatically?

Comment: I don't think so, when you delete a programm a lot of the files still stay on your computer. 99% of the time this is anoying but it can be usefull in this case.